# Encontrar coincidencias de varias columnas contra una sola columna y hacer un data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

buen día. Disculpen, he estado intentado encontrar las coincidencias de las siguientes 3 diferentes tablas en otra única tabla que es la combinación de las anteriores (no la puse aqui porque ya era muy largo el post, pero es literalmente las tres anteriores pegadas). Verán, **ejecute Blastp de un organismo modelo contra otros 3 y ahora quisiera saber que genes hit se comparten entre todos los organismos**

```
#Tabla 1 Hits a Organismo1 
|OrganismoM |Organismo1 |
|gen_pep01  |hsa_pep01  |
|gen_pep01  |hsa_pep02  |
|gen_pep01  |hsa_pep03  |
|gen_pep03  |hsa_pep11  |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |

#Tabla 2 Hits a Organismo2 
|OrganismoM |Organismo2 |
|gen_pep02  |rno_pep14  |
|gen_pep05  |rno_pep22  |
|gen_pep05  |rno_pep23  |
|gen_pep05  |rno_pep25  |

#Tabla 3 Hits a Organismo3   
|OrganismoM |Organismo3 |
|gen_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep03  |dre_pep08  |
|gen_pep08  |dre_pep99  |
```

Lo que buco obtener es una tabla que me indique los hits de cada gen en cada organismo, algo así:

```
#Tabla final
|OrganismoM |Organismo1 |Organismo2 |Organismo3 |
|gen_pep01  |hsa_pep01  |rno_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep01  |hsa_pep02  |rno_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep01  |hsa_pep03  |rno_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep02  |rno_pep14  |N/A        |N/A        |
|gen_pep03  |hsa_pep11  |dre_pep08  |N/A        |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |rno_pep22  |N/A        |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |rno_pep23  |N/A        |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |rno_pep25  |N/A        |
|gen_pep08  |drep_pep99 |N/A        |N/A        |
```

Para esto, **lo que hice** fue crear una tabla de dos columnas que contuviera las 3 anteriores y comence a hacer `match` entre esta tabla creada y cada una de las 3 tablas, he estado utilizando un código como este para cada organismo para al final crear un data frame con las columnas que necesite

```
library(xlsx)
HitsOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneral<-read.xlsx("HitsOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneral.xlsx",1) #Tabla convinación de las 3 tablas
HitsOrganismoMvsOrganismo1<-read.xlsx("Tabla1.xlsx",1) #Tabla 1
MatchOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneralVSOrganismoMvsOrganismo1<-match(HitsOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneral$OrganismoM,HitsOrganismoMvsOrganismo1$OrganismoM)
IndexMatchOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneralVSOrganismoMvsOrganismo1<-!is.na(MatchOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneralVSOrganismoMvsOrganismo)
Index2MatchOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneralVSOrganismoMvsOrganismo1<-OrganismoMvsOrganismo1$Organismo1[MatchOrganismoMvsOrganismosGeneralVSOrganismoMvsOrganismo1]
```

Asi con cada tabla, el problema es que estos match me dan únicamente el nombre del primer gene hit de Organismo de comparación por cada gen de Organismo Modelo, obteniendo una tabla asi(marque con "*"):

```
|OrganismoM |Organismo1 |Organismo2 |Organismo3 |
|gen_pep01  |*hsa_pep01*|rno_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep01  |*hsa_pep01*|rno_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep01  |*hsa_pep01*|rno_pep01  |dre_pep01  |
|gen_pep02  |rno_pep14  |N/A        |N/A        |
|gen_pep03  |hsa_pep11  |dre_pep08  |N/A        |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |*rno_pep22*|N/A        |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |*rno_pep22*|N/A        |
|gen_pep05  |hsa_pep20  |*rno_pep22*|N/A        |
|gen_pep08  |drep_pep99 |N/A        |N/A        |
```

En lugar de una que si hiciera distinción entro todos los genes hit ¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionar esto? O si conocen un método distinto también lo apreciaría mucho. Muchas gracias por su tiempo, de verdad, y que tengan un excelente día!

Comment: Hola Luis T! Bienvenido. Para tener mayor posibilidad de ayuda recomiendo que incluyas un ejemplo que pueda ser replicado por otros usuarios. Puedes usar la función `dput()` sobre las tablas`dput(tabla)`, o parte de ellas `dput(head(tabla))` e incluir la salida en tu post. Eventualmente la solución a tu pregunta puede ser encontrada en los paquetes `data.table` o `dplyr`: https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/. Si lo que deseas es unir las tablas, puedes usar las funciones para hacer "join"

Comment: Si lo que deseas es reorganizar la tabla y pasar las líneas de cada organismo para columnas, puedes ver las  funciones para "reshape" en el link https://atrebas.github.io/post/2019-03-03-datatable-dplyr/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es hacer un `full_join`

```
df1<-read.table(text = "
    OrganismoM Organismo1 
gen_pep01  hsa_pep01  
gen_pep01  hsa_pep02  
gen_pep01  hsa_pep03  
gen_pep03  hsa_pep11  
gen_pep05  hsa_pep20  ", header = T)

df2<-read.table(text = "
    OrganismoM Organismo2 
gen_pep02  rno_pep14  
gen_pep05  rno_pep22  
gen_pep05  rno_pep23  
gen_pep05  rno_pep25  ", header = T)

df3<-read.table(text = "OrganismoM Organismo3 
gen_pep01  dre_pep01  
gen_pep03  dre_pep08  
gen_pep08  dre_pep99  ", header =T)

library(dplyr)

df1%>%full_join(df2)%>%
    full_join(df3)%>%
arrange(OrganismoM)
```

Con esto obtienes la tabla que buscas.